# What does an Android-encrypted SD card do/look like on PC

Tags: external-sd, encryption

Long story short - my Galaxy Active S8 apparently got wet inside, and stopped working (although I think I can revive).  I've let the [Samsung microSD card](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/memory-cards/microsdxc-evo-select-memory-card-w--adapter-128gb--2017-model--mb-me128ga-am/) for almost 24 hours, and as it's simply a card I believe the data should be easily retrievable as I've had SD cards get wet before, but would work after drying.

However, when I put the microSD card in my PC, doesn't show up in the Windows Explorer like normal.  I don't see an additional drive pop up at all.

I can't remember if I encrypted my card or not.  So, I'm hoping I did, and that's why it's not appearing as mounted on my PC.  What would an encrypted SD Card do, or look like, when inserted in a computer?  Would it appear as a drive, but prevent any access - or would it simply not show up at all?

Comment: Android/Linux use different file-system formats than Windows. Windows can't read them at all so they may not be displayed (depends on the used Windows version and revision). Also make sure to check hat is displayed in the disk management view. It shows more details than the Explorer.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks for that comment! I have Ubuntu on a separate drive - let me boot in to that, cross my fingers, and see if it works!

Comment: Bah, nope. Nothing appeared or showed up. Disk Management doesn't show a drive get connected either.

Comment: @beeshyams any way to confirm? I'm trying to get my phone working again, but would be surprised if it's dead.  If so, are there ways to retrieve the media (a yes/no is fine, I get that's a big question)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109411/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-beeshyams).

Comment: Run `dmsg -w` on Linux before connecting SD card. That's the simplest way to know if card is detected properly regardless of whether it's encrypted, or the filesystem is broken etc.

Comment: @IrfanLatif - Ah! I ran `dmesg -w` and got the following, primarily "no support for card's volts" and "card claims to support voltages belo defined range".  [Screenshot here](https://i.imgur.com/Uqro0kb.jpg)

Comment: @BruceWayne that indicates the failure is at hardware level. RIP!

Comment: @IrfanLatif - [Noooooo](https://media.tenor.com/images/e94f37436c75ccb038a1f10d7cca5450/tenor.gif)! That means it's 100% unable to be recovered, even by a service (and I'd assume it'd be really expensive)?

Comment: @BruceWayne you can try your luck. Hard to say anything.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for your help. If you want, put the `dmesg -w` troubleshooting tip in an answer, and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at it with gparted in Linux.  If it's toast, it is.
Give it a try ... it is the standard partition mounting gui tool in Linux.

Else take it to a repair center from your Phone Service Provider.  Give them a try.

Comment: Do you have any links/more info on how to use gparted?

Comment: `parted`/`gparted`/`fdisk`/`gdisk` are partitioning tools. Kernel does not recognize the card at hardware level. There are no block devices evaluated, so no partition table, no `/dev` or `/sys` entries. What would `gparted` do there! It simply won't be aware of the existence of the card. @BruceWayne please update your question with the actual problem to avoid irrelevant answers.

Comment: @IrfanLatif - Yeah, I need to edit my OP...it spiraled from my original question.  In any case, for now I consider this specific question closed thanks to your tips :)